# Rails query WHERE clause using OR

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, boolean, where-clause

i have 2 individual RAILS queries that both work fine on their own:

```
@charts = Chart.where(:patient_id => @emailpatient.id)

@charts = Chart.where(:patient_id => @sharepatient.id)
```

that i want to simply combine into a single 'OR' query. i tried:

```
@charts = Chart.where(:patient_id => @sharepatient.id OR :patient_id => @emailpatient.id)
```

and

```
@charts = Chart.where("patient_id => @sharepatient.id OR patient_id => @emailpatient.id")
```

and various other variations and cant get it to work. Where am i going astray?

Comment: You should get the queries in console where you ran ”rails server”. What does it say there?

Comment: Or rather, this is either syntax error (is uppercase OR available as comparison operator?)

Comment: @Smar the first line, he does not write the condition in a string => out. Then he does but does not interpolate both values.

Comment: `@charts = Chart.where(:conditions => ["patient_id => ? OR patient_id => ?", @sharepatient.id, @emailpatient.id])`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do

```
@charts = Chart.where(:patient_id => [@emailpatient.id, @sharepatient.id])
```

Comment: This translates to a `WHERE patient_id IN (...)` clause, which is logically equivalent but has the advantage of working for N ids.

Answer (score 5):

You got it slightly wrong.

```
@charts = Chart.where("patient_id = ?  OR patient_id = ?", @sharepatient.id, @emailpatient.id)
```